# a simple frame-differencing

Tags: opencv, frame

The background scene often evolves over time because, for instance, the lighting condition might change (for example,from sunrise to sunset), or because new objects could be added or removed from the background.
Therefore, it is necessary to dynamically build a model of the background scene.
based on above, I wrote a simple frame differencing code.It works good But it's very slow.
how can I make it faster? Any suggestions?

```
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp >
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>

    int main()
    {
        cv::Mat gray; // current gray-level image
     cv::Mat background; // accumulated background
     cv::Mat backImage; // background image
     cv::Mat foreground; // foreground image
     // learning rate in background accumulation
     double learningRate;
     int threshold; // threshold for foreground extraction
     cv::VideoCapture capture("video.mp4");

     // check if video successfully opened
     if (!capture.isOpened())
     return 0;
     // current video frame
     cv::Mat frame;
     double rate= capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
     int delay= 1000/rate;
     // foreground binary image
     //cv::Mat foreground;
      cv::Mat output;
      bool stop(false);
      while (!stop){
          if(!capture.read(frame))
              break;

          cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
      cv::namedWindow("back");
         cv::imshow("back",gray);

      // initialize background to 1st frame
     if (background.empty())
     gray.convertTo(background, CV_32F);
     // convert background to 8U
     background.convertTo(backImage,CV_8U);
     // compute difference between image and background
     cv::absdiff(backImage,gray,foreground);

         // apply threshold to foreground image
     cv::threshold(foreground,output, 10,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
     // accumulate background
     cv::accumulateWeighted(gray, background, 0.01, output);


         cv::namedWindow("out");
         cv::imshow("out",output);
     if (cv::waitKey(delay)>=0)
     stop= true; 
      }

     }
```

Comment: OpenCV has something similar already implemented, maybe you can take some inspiration from [this](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html#gsc.tab=0) example. The give references to the papers from which they took the implementation.  However, in my experience these things are generally quite slow.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have to write a reall time moving object tracker. Do you know any reall time approach for this subject?

Comment: You can start with the link posted above, and convince yourself that opencv methods works better and faster than any custom code you'll write (until you get some more experience). Can you also post your execution time? This code can't be that slow...

Comment: probably you should use `if (cv::waitKey(1)>=0)`. Your code has a few minor errors (as pointed out in the answer below), but I think the bottleneck is the `waitKey`.

Comment: Do you need Floating point precision for your background image? You could try addWeighted with beta=1-alpha, but not sure whether it is faster (you might get some overhead but you don't have to convert to 8 bit for each frame. Your `delay` value doesn't care about the processing time needed (e.g. if you have 25 fps your delay would be 40 ms but if your processing time is 20 ms you'd wait 60 ms between each frame instead of 40 ms). In addition, cv::waitKey isn't very precise (on windows system waitKey and might wait longer than you want it to)

Comment: Dear Miki and Mika ,thanks for your suggestion. Both of  you are right. I changed my waitkey to (cv::waitKey(delay/2)>=0) and it maked my code faster. I'm starter in opencv and c++. So now I should search about processing time?

Answer (score 2):

I modified and corrected some parts of your code:

- in the while loop you call to `cv::namedWindow("back")` and  `cv::namedWindow("out")`, this is only necessary to do once.
- you use `if (background.empty())` to see if the array is empty or not, this is just necessary for the first cycle in which the matrix `background` is empty because in the remaining matrix will be filled, so that your code does not error the first cycle initialize to zero `background=cv::Mat::zeros(rows,cols,CV_32F)`  taking into account the type and size that will be required in the iteration while loop. Also it does not affect the operation of accumulation.

Here the updated code:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat gray; // current gray-level image
 cv::Mat background; // accumulated background
 cv::Mat backImage; // background image
 cv::Mat foreground; // foreground image
 // learning rate in background accumulation
 double learningRate;
 int threshold; // threshold for foreground extraction
 cv::VideoCapture capture("C:/Users/Pedram91/Pictures/Camera   Roll/videoplayback.mp4");////C:/Users/Pedram91/Downloads/Video/videoplayback.mp4//C:/FLIR.mp4

 // check if video successfully opened
 if (!capture.isOpened())
 return 0;
 // current video frame
 cv::Mat frame;
 double rate= capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
 int delay= 1000/rate;
 // foreground binary image
 //cv::Mat foreground;
  cv::Mat output;
  bool stop(false);

  cv::namedWindow("back");//This should go here,You only need to call once
  cv::namedWindow("out");//This should go here,You only need to call once

  int cols=capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
  int rows=capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);      

  background=cv::Mat::zeros(rows,cols,CV_32F);//this will save the "if (background.empty())" in the while loop


  while (!stop){
      if(!capture.read(frame))
          break;

     cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

     cv::imshow("back",gray);

  // initialize background to 1st frame
// if (background.empty())
 gray.convertTo(background, CV_32F);
 // convert background to 8U
 background.convertTo(backImage,CV_8U);
 // compute difference between image and background
 cv::absdiff(backImage,gray,foreground);

     // apply threshold to foreground image
 cv::threshold(foreground,output, 10,255,cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
 // accumulate background
 cv::accumulateWeighted(gray, background, 0.01, output);



  cv::imshow("out",output);
 if (cv::waitKey(delay)>=0)
 stop= true; 
  }

 }
```

Comment: Can you explain where this code is an improvement over OP's code? Did you compared the performance? Code only answer are not very clear, consider improving it with some explanation

Comment: Check the answer again

Comment: much better. As you can see I _formatted_ your answer. Learn how to use formatting options to produce better answers. Also, please double check my edit and see if it's ok for you, or edit it accordingly.

Comment: I'm new and I'm still learning how to handle the website, impressed me as corrected my bad form to write, Greetings from Colombia

Comment: Yes I agree that's my answer.

Comment: Dear Esteban Benavides Castro,thank you for updating my code. As I said I'm new in c++ and opencv . So your updating was so helpful for me.:))